# Actualiza imagen desde servidor hacia mi app usando Picasso

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

Estoy desarrollando una app de Android en la cual se carga una imagen de bienvenida desde el servidor, mi idea es ir actualizando esa imagen o la url desde el servidor, utilizo la librería Picasso para obtener imágenes desde el server pero al ubicar una url especifica ya no podría cambiarla.

Este es el código en Kotlin

```
private fun chargueImage(){

            Picasso.get()
                .load("https://imgur.com/gallery/TIbCGuf")
                .into(imagView)}
```

Esto es lo que hace mi actual codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo a través de Picasso u otra forma?

Comment: Ambas opciones son posibles, puedes cambiar la url o modificar la imagen que retorna esa url (siempre que la url apunte a tu servidor). Pero picasso no tiene nada que ver con esto, en todo caso tu problema sería cómo obtener la url. Mas allá de configurar el cache, la librería que utilices para cargar la imagen no tiene mayor implicación en este asunto. Y por favor lee [ask].

Comment: Al publicar la app en la Play Store ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la url?¿Como actualizo la imagen si al subir otra obtendré otra url distinta? Lo que necesito es actualizar esa url desde el servidor ya que al estar la app ya publicada no podre hacerlo

Comment: Para empezar, tienes un servidor? Dices que quieres cambiar la url desde el servidor pero en tu ejemplo la imagen está en "imgur.com" y no creo que ese sitio sea tuyo.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo perfectamente, quiero cambiar la url en el codigo remotamente por ejemplo tengo .load(myurl.com) y quiero actualizar esa url (texto)  de forma remota .load(myurl2.com)

Comment: Bien, ahora tiene un poco más de sentido. Dada tu escasez de conocimiento, probablemente lo mejor sea que utilices algo como [Remote Config](https://youtu.be/_CXXVFPO6f0)